# Word Quick Parts and Sharepoint 2013 content types

Tags: 2013, word, quick-parts

I have a question regarding Quick Parts.

I created a new content type with three columns and added a document template to that content type. Then I created a fourth column 'by hand' directly in the document library. When I adjust the Document template everything works fine (I mean all the columns appear in the Quick Parts).

A workflow creates an item in the document library when a list item in a list is created (the list has the same columns as the doc lib).

What happens is that the document is filled out with the fourth information (the column added in the library) and the other three columns (from the content type) are not filled it.

Any idea why? Thank you!